# What is the house hourglass of Hufflepuff filled with?

Tags: harry-potter

> Giant hourglasses set in niches along one wall in a corner of the entrance hall record the points for all to see; Gryffindor's is filled with rubies, Ravenclaw's with sapphires, and Slytherin's with emeralds.  (Source: [HP Lexicon, "Points"](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/hogwarts/points.html))

But is there any canon info (books, JKR interviews, and if all else fails, movies) on what Hufflepuff's hourglass is filled with?

Comment: Imported angry hornets that are tired of being underestimated. No, I kid. This is a very good question! Now you've got me curious... :)

Comment: Yellow sapphire, citrine, flourite, yellow diamonds?

Comment: How about tiger's eye?

Comment: Considering Hufflepuff's usual House Cup performance, it was filled primarily with air.

Comment: @GabeWillard harsh man, harsh....

Comment: Sand.  Hufflepuff actually always won, but they let the other houses think they did so they wouldn't feel bad about it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

JK Rowling just replied to someone on Twitter saying they are diamonds.

> **@HarmonicalHeroL** @jk_rowling @lumos What are the gems in the Hufflepuff hourglass?… Oh! Also thanks for all that you do. :)
>
> <sup>[Twitter, 2:17 PM on 25 Apr 2014](https://twitter.com/HarmonicalHero/status/459682676539019264)</sup>

JKR promptly replied:

> **@jk_rowling:** @HarmonicalHero Diamonds, of course.  Because that's what Hufflepuffs are (some a little rougher than others). X
>
> <sup>[Twitter, 2:20 PM on 25 Apr 2014](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/459683482575572992)</sup>

Here’s a screenshot of the tweets:

[image]

Comment: Come now, you ought to know better.  where's the hand-drawn circle?! (On the other hand, good answer. I'd upvote but I reached my limit for today already).

Comment: @Zibbobz Here, have [some circles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pSmFm.png).

Comment: On the other hand, http://web.archive.org/web/20111223103041/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=51 claims that Rowling doesn't have a Twitter account.

Comment: @b_jonas She does now. As you can see, the Twitter handle has a blue checkmark next to it. This means this account is verified by Twitter to be owned by the person who the Twitter account is supposed to represent. It's nearly impossible to get that on a fan or parody account.

Answer (score 25):

**ETA:**4.30.14 - I was going to post JKR's tweet too, but someone beat me to it! Good show, User25498! :)

<sub>This answer contains ten 100x100 images. If you don't like images with answers this may not be the post for you. I felt the subject matter warranted images to enhance the answer, as it's a visual subject. There is no gratuitous intent and all images are sourced. This is long because I wasn't able to place the images and text side by side.</sub>

I did some research into yellow gems. Of course Hufflepuff's colors are both yellow and black, so I did consider black gems and minerals, but concluded that the color would more likely be yellow. Black is so stark and can be gloomy, plus it would be somewhat close in shade to Ravenclaw's sapphires. I considered obsidian as a possibility, but obsidian is more like glass; I don't believe it's a gem. Further, it's very brittle and can break off in sharpened wedges that can easily cut. So, yes, yellow I think! **Edited to Add: Hufflepuff's gems are indeed yellow, according to [Pottermore](http://www.pottermore.com/en/great-hall) -- the link goes to the Great Hall at Pottermore and you'll need a Pottermore account to access it. Just an FYI.**

While I'm sure I wasn't able to perform a perfectly exhaustive search, the follow gems/minerals are what I ended up thinking are more likely candidates (and some I end up ruling out). I am including very small images so anyone reading this can see exactly what gemstone I'm referring to. Here's what I came up with:

---

**Yellow Citrine:**

[image: Yellow Citrine]

Source: [Media Merchant Circle](http://tinyurl.com/79m69eb)

According to [Gemology Online](http://www.gemologyonline.com/citrine.html), Citrine today is mostly produced by heating Amethyst to 900° F, at which temperature it turns a green/yellow color. Emeralds, rubies, and blue sapphires occur naturally. As well, the element that Hufflepuff corresponds with is [earth](http://www.lelandra.com/tarotbook/harrypotterelements.htm), not fire. The citrine picture shows how green undertones come through in the color of the gem.

Yellow Citrine? No

---

**Yellow Chrysoberyl:**

[image: Yellow Chrysoberyl]

Source: [Crystal's Crystals](http://www.crystalscrystals.com/locator2/lt-gold-yel-chrysoberyl.jpg)

I love this gem and wish I could definitely say this is likely the Hufflepuffs' gems in the hourglass, but I'm thinking it may not qualify. Chrysoberyl wasn't seen in the West until the [1800s](http://www.gemologyonline.com/chrysoberyl.html), although it's not clarified whether "the West" includes Europe and the UK, or just North America. It's really the perfect color -- yellow, but with shades that add depth.

Chrysoberyl? Possibly

---

**Yellow Diamond:**

[image: Diamonds -- Yellow, Clear, Green, Dark Amber]

Source: [Gemology Online](http://www.gemologyonline.com/diamond.html)

While yellow diamonds are more common than clear, and while beautiful, diamonds are expensive (are there any gems more expensive than diamonds per carat?). Perhaps witches and wizards had a source that allowed them to get valuables quite easily; however, what we see in canon doesn't support that. Wizards don't conjure money or food (Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration).

Diamonds? No.

---

**Yellow Opal:**

[image: Yellow Opal]

Source: [Jeweler Online](http://www.jeweleronlinestore.com/opal/yellow-opal-loose.jpg)

Opal is not a gem; it's a [hardened jelly-like substance](http://www.gemologyonline.com/opal.html). It's also quite opaque, which makes it a fairly dull substance. As well, opals have a dark reputation and have been the center of [numerous superstitions](http://www.gemologyonline.com/opal.html).

Opal? No.

---

**Yellow Sapphire:**

[image: Yellow Sapphire]

Source: [Yellow Sapphires](http://yellowsapphires.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/yellow-sapphire-sri-lanka-1334.jpg)

The sapphire is tried and true by Hogwarts, as the Ravenclaws have blue sapphires in their hourglass. The Sapphire is a good possibility because its history dates back to [7th century BC](http://www.gemologyonline.com/sapphire.html), which fits within Hogwarts' time frame.

Sapphire? Good possibility.

---

**Yellow Quartz:**

[image: Yellow Quartz]

Source: [Four Corners and More](http://www.fourcornersandmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/yellow-quartz.jpg)

Too chunky and opaque to be a proper hourglass gem in its natural form. Cut, it tends to be more brown than yellow. It is also quite [ubiquitous](http://www.gemologyonline.com/quartz.html), having been credited for just about *everything* at one point or another.

Yellow Quartz? No.

---

**Yellow Spinel:**

[image: Yellow Spinel]

Source: [Vendio](http://tinyurl.com/888hbvr)

Gemology Online, again, reports the two-inch faceted "ruby" in the center of the British Imperial Crown was [recently identified as a spinel](http://www.gemologyonline.com/spinel.html). So we know the spinel is available in the UK. This is another gem with rich colors, that would look good in the Hufflepuffs' hourglass. Blue spinels have been found in England, [dating back to the Roman occupation](http://www.gemologyonline.com/spinel.html) (51 BC to 400 AD). Spinels come in a variety of colors, including yellow; the existence of spinels in the UK so far back in history make the spinel a good candidate.

Spinel? Excellent possibility.

---

**Yellow Topaz:**

[image: Yellow Topaz]

Source: [Aussie Sapphire](https://aussiesapphire.files.wordpress.com/2006/11/imperial-topaz.jpg)

A bit honey-colored and perhaps too dark for Hufflepuff's colors of primary yellow and black. Also not a particularly unusual gem.

Topaz? No.

---

**Yellow Tourmaline:**

[image: Yellow Tourmaline]

Source: [GG Gems](http://www.gggems.com/images/To%20yellow/Yellow_tourmaline_511aXXL.jpg)

Tourmaline is a very hard and durable gem and it does occur in yellow. Interestingly, when heated, tourmaline attracts dust and particles in the air, which vaguely corresponds to Hufflepuff's earth element. However, tourmaline was not introduced to Europe until the [1700s](http://www.gemologyonline.com/tourmaline.html).

Tourmaline? No.

---

**Yellow Zircons:**

[image: Yellow Zircon]

Source: [Gem Rock Auctions](http://static-us.gemrockauctions.com/uploads/images/155000-159999/159515/159515_1264106402.jpg)

Zircon is not the same as cubic zirconia; it can be a brittle gem. Furthermoe, zircon contains trace amounts of the [radioactive minerals](http://www.gemologyonline.com/zircon.html) hafnium, uranium and thorium. Although I believe these are all mined from the earth (Hufflepuff's element), I think Hogwarts wouldn't use anything that might put its students at risk, however unlikely the possibility, when other options were available. Would the Wizarding world know about radioactivity? Possibly, but under a different context -- more likely, I think, radioactive elements would be known as poisons, if they are known at all. My sense is that J.K. Rowling wasn't considering whether wizards knew about radioactivity when she created her universe, but as uranium is a naturally occurring substance, perhaps master alchemists or potions masters were at least aware of its existence.

Zircon? No.

---

I'm going to go with the yellow spinel, especially with the long history of spinels in the UK, the use of a spinel in the crown jewels (showing it's an important gem), and it's rich yellow color. **My answer: Yellow Spinel.**

---

**ETA 10.14.12:**

[image: *Prisoner of Azkaban* - movie - House hourglasses with jewels]

In the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*, the hourglasses with the jewels are visible behind the high table. Hufflepuff's jewels are indeed yellow in that shot.

---

[image: House hourglasses with jewels at the Wizarding World of Harry Potter in Orlando, FL]

The Hufflepuff jewels in the hourglasses at the Wizarding World of Harry Potter in Orlando, FL, appear to be yellow **and** black. I tend to *think* that the jewels in canon would be just yellow, as no other house has multiple colors, and this is reflected in the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*. I also can't quite tell if the jewels in the Wizarding World of Harry Potter Hufflepuff hourglass actually has black jewels in there or if it's shadows in between the yellow jewels. Anyone who's been to the Wizarding World of Harry Potter, please let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't Opal being dull make it a good possibility for Hufflepuff.

Comment: -1 for lack of hand-drawn circles.

Comment: @DVK hand-drawn circle? what?

Comment: @naxa -they are [required for a successful answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/119280) on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @DVK ah I see. but a -1 for that?! not reading meta memes? honestly, why SE expects people read anything else than the FAQ? or is -1 a joke?

Comment: @naxa - yep, you got it, it was a joke. I actually upvoted the answer.

Comment: @DVK ah I'M bad at this... :)

Comment: according to the new updated Pottermore in the 'Time-Turner' moment with Harry and Hermione, Hufflepuff's gems are indeed yellow, as to what type they are, I'll go with @Slytherincess Yellow Spinel

Comment: @BP_Phoenix -- Thanks for leaving this comment. It prompts me to go check out the second half of *Prisoner of Azkaban* at Pottermore. I have a great affection for *PoA* -- it was when I read this book that I became captivated by the series. </random blathering> I'm glad I got the Hufflepuff color right :)

Comment: @Slytherincess -- I was unsure if there were black gems in there as well or if they were just shadows, what do you think? your captivation of this series is very evident in your thorough knowledge and obvious research displayed in your comments, they are a pleasure to read. I only started reading the books after GoF came out and after the first movie, since then, pretty much the same thing :) lol

Comment: @BP_Phoenix - Thanks for your nice comment, and, yeah, I admit my geekiness re: HP. Coincidentally, I also started reading the series after *Goblet of Fire* was published, so back in 2002, I believe. Well, I read the first book in 1998, but it didn't grab me so I didn't continue reading the series. But thanks for your nice comments -- they made me smile :) I found a couple pics online that suggested the other house gems included black gems, but it was too hard to see to say yes or no definitively. If you watch PS/SS the movie, the hourglasses are clearly shown in the Sorting scene.

Comment: An excellent answer which is, unfortunately 98% wrong. You guessed right but only by using a shotgun :-)

Comment: The possible flaw in your reasoning: "are there any gems more expensive than diamonds per carat?"  Yes, absolutely. Not only do diamonds range quite extensively in value based on color, clarity, luster, cut, and size (of yellow diamonds, only those that are exceptionally bright yellow... canary yellow... are prized above clear diamonds), but other gems are rarer and more expensive, such as top-notch examples of gem-quality benitoite.  Still, an excellent and comprehensive answer :)

Comment: Additionally, diamonds are only expensive currently because DeBeers manipulates the market to keep them that way.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots DeBeers are a bunch of Hufflepuffs.

Comment: @randal'thor: Now there's a scary bit of "Hufflepuff Conspiracy" headcanon...

Answer (score 3):

What about amber? Although it's not a rock, sometimes it can be yellow. Also, it can be darker. Think- yellow and black to yellow, dark yellow and dark brown. Although the majority of amber is dark brown, I have a piece of it that is yellow.

Comment: This is a good guess, but unfortunately the 'correct' answer (correct according to JKR or whoever manages her Twitter account) has already been given.